# How can I deallocate a pointer in vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, c++17, delete-operator

I want to erase a pointer in the vector but I also want to empty the pointer content so that it does not store an `A` object and delete the pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
private:
  int a;

public:
  A(int a): a(a){}
  int getValue(){return a;}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  auto a (new A(3));
  auto b (new A(4));

  A *c = a;

  std::cout << "Pointer a: " << a << '\n';
  std::cout << "Pointer b: " << b << '\n';
  std::cout << "Pointer c: " << c << '\n';

  std::vector<A*> v = {a, b};
  for (auto i : v)
    std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << '\n';
  v.erase(v.begin());

  std::cout << "Pointer c: " << c->getValue() << '\n';

  for (auto i : v)
    std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

When I print Pointer `c` after erasing `a`, it still prints 3

Comment: `v.erase()` removes the pointer from the vector, but doesn't  call `delete` on it.

Comment: Yeah but how can I deallocate the pointer in the vector and set its content to nullptr?

Comment: You call `delete` on it before (e.g. `delete *v.begin();`). I don't know what you mean by _"set its content to nullptr"_.

Comment: Whenever I delete a pointer I write `delete p;` and then `p = nulltpr;` so when I print `p`, it prints `0x0`.

Comment: Writing `*v.begin() = nullptr;` won't affect the original pointer variable, since you stored a copy of that pointer in the vector.

Comment: Why not use a smart pointer like [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which can be easily deleted using the `delete` keyword...

Comment: @Ruks I think you meant *without needing to use* the delete keyword?

Comment: @jeremyFriesner Oh, I mixed up shared_ptr and unique_ptr... Yes, you wouldn't need to call delete, it will dispose of it automatically after it goes out of scope...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
delete v[0];
v[0] = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but... using C++17 you can use smart pointers, as suggested by Rusk.

This can easily solve the problem of ownership and deletion for the vector.

It seems to me that you need shared pointers (`std::shared_ptr`) for `a`, `b` and `v` and a weak pointer (`std::weak_ptr`) for `c`.

So you can use `c` if (and only if) there is at least a `std::shared_ptr` that maintain the ownership of the pointer.

The following is a simplified example without `a` and `b`, with `v` renamed as `vsp` (for "vector of shared pointers") and `c` renamed as `wp` (for "weak pointer").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A 
 {
   private:
      int a;

   public:
      A (int a0) : a{a0}
       { }

      int getValue ()
       {return a;}
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vsp;

   vsp.emplace_back( new A{3} );
   vsp.emplace_back( new A{4} );

   std::weak_ptr<A> wp { vsp.front() };

   std::cout << "Pointer 0:  " << vsp[0] << " (" << vsp[0]->getValue() << ')' 
      << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Pointer 1:  " << vsp[1] << " (" << vsp[1]->getValue() << ')' 
      << std::endl;

   if ( auto sp = wp.lock() )
      std::cout << "Pointer wp: " << sp << " (" << sp->getValue() << ')'
         << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "Pointer wp: <deleted>" << std::endl;

   vsp.clear();

   std::cout << "Vector cleared" << std::endl;

   if ( auto sp = wp.lock() )
      std::cout << "Pointer wp: " << sp << " (" << sp->getValue() << ')'
         << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "Pointer wp: <deleted>" << std::endl;
 }
```